# Nodejs Express Web APP - Consume API - Token

Tags: node.js, api, express, web-applications, ejs

I'm new with nodejs and i have a situation.

I have a **WebApp with nodejs, express and EJS templates** and I consume an external API.

I have to impletate the login and I dont know how handle the TOKEN that API provides me

Until now I stole a TOKEN in posleman and put it in config file so in mi nodejs calls's (service )i consume that.

I dont know wath to do now; how handle and store the token.

I will be so grateful if someone bring me some help or orientation

Comment: what is the API?

Comment: Api is in nodejs too... return a jwt token.